# Create Memorystream of type pdf and return to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, memorystream

I have to create a blank PDF with a simple text message and return it to the browser. I don't have to use any third-party PDF library like iTextSharp, PDFDocument, etc.

I am using `MemoryStream` but a corrupted PDF is getting generated.

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ms.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test message"), 0, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test message").Length);
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + id.ToString() + ".pdf");
 return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
```

What I am missing?

Comment: You can't just write bytes to a stream and expect it to be a PDF. That's not how a PDF document is structured.  You will need to create the PDF using a library like you suggested and then return it like you do already.

Comment: @RyanThomas is there no way to create memorystream of type pdf. is it mandate to use third party PDF library to create PDF.?

Comment: A PDF file has a unique structure to it. It is possible to write that byte structure to a stream if you know it. Try this: create a new .txt document and add some content, rename to .pdf, try to open. It won't.

Comment: A memory stream, just like any other stream, is just bytes. It has no file type. File types apply to its content.  You need a library to generate that content and write it to the stream. You can't write some text to a stream and expect it to render as a picture just because you specified an image content type. This would be no different than changing a text file's extension to `png` and expect it to act like an image

Comment: _"I don't have to use any third-party PDF library"_ - you "_don't have to_" or you are "_not allowed to_" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically created a TXT file and sent that to the Browser declaring it as a PDF.

PDF has its own file format. Old versions of the PDF standard such as PDF 1.2 can be written in a text-like format. The Wayback Machine [has a copy of the PDF 1.2 specification](https://web.archive.org/web/19961219053721/http://www.adobe.com:80/supportservice/devrelations/PDFS/TN/PDFSPEC.PDF).

You probably want to benefit of newer versions of the PDF standard. And maybe you don't want to invest the time reading and understanding 400 pages. Also, you don't want huge string templates, but a more expressive way of creating PDF files. So, a library can save you a lot of time and effort.

Anyway, you could read that specification and come up with something like

```
string template = @"
%PDF-1.2 
4 0 obj << >> 
stream 
BT/ 12 Tf({0})' ET 
endstream 
endobj
3 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Contents 4 0 R >> endobj
2 0 obj << /Kids [3 0 R ] /Count 1 /Type /Pages /MediaBox [ 0 0 99 99 ] >> endobj
1 0 obj << /Pages 2 0 R /Type /Catalog >> endobj
trailer << /Root 1 0 R >>
%%EOF
";
string text = "Text message";
string pdf = string.Format(template, text);
```

It has:

- A `%PDF-1.2` header as described in chapter 5.2
- Various objects as described in chapter 4
- Dictionaries inside `<< >>` as described in chapter 4.7
- A stream between `stream` and `endstream` as described in chapter 4.8
- A text object, introduced with `BT` and ending with `ET` as described in Figure 8.1
- Text font manipulation with `Tf` as described in chapter 8.7.3
- A text string between `(` and `)` as described in chapter 4.4. I'm using a .NET `{0}` placeholder here.
- A page with the required `MediaBox` defining the size of the page as described in chapter 6.4
- A `trailer` as described in chapter 5.5, ending with `%%EOF`, containing a mandatory `/Root` entry.

You kinda read this PDF "bottom up". The trailer refers to Object `1 0`, which refers to the pages `2 0`, which refers to one page `3 0`, which refers to content `4 0`.

Comment: OP: Don't misinterpret this as Thomas is suggesting you should actually do it like this. He is merely showing you that it is possible _if you know the file format and its quirks_. Creating a PDF of a more recent version like this would be an incredible hassle, which people already have taken upon themselves for you.

Comment: @Fildor: thanks. A good point, which I included in the answer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I will try this approach